# Timeout is not able to sent via pika.Blocking connection

Tags: python, pika

I am trying to write a client program to recieve from the rabbitmq server, with which I want to set the timeout. After the specified time the client should stop consuming for the messages from the queue and exit.

I am using the pika with Blocking connection . I saw the add_timeout(delay,callback) defined in the blocking connection ,but when I am trying to use that I am getting the following error as follows.

```
 [*] Waiting for logs. To exit press CTRL+C
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/workspace/Misc/misc/pika_samples/log_recieve.py", line 39, in <module>
    channel.start_consuming()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pika/adapters/blocking_connection.py", line 293, in start_consuming
    self.transport.connection.process_data_events()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pika/adapters/blocking_connection.py", line 103, in process_data_events
    self.process_timeouts()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pika/adapters/blocking_connection.py", line 160, in process_timeouts
    self._timeouts[timeout_id]['handler']()
TypeError: callback() takes exactly 4 arguments (0 given)
```

This is my client program. I am not running any server to simulate the timeout condition.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import pika
import sys

connection = pika.BlockingConnection(pika.ConnectionParameters(host='localhost'))
channel = connection.channel()
channel.exchange_declare(exchange='topic_logs',type='topic')
result = channel.queue_declare(exclusive=True)
queue_name = result.method.queue
binding_keys = "#"
for binding_key in binding_keys:
    channel.queue_bind(exchange='topic_logs',queue=queue_name,
                   routing_key=binding_key)

print ' [*] Waiting for logs. To exit press CTRL+C'
def callback(ch, method, properties, body):
    print " [x] %r:%r" % (method.routing_key, body,)
    channel.stop_consuming()
connection.add_timeout(10, callback)
channel.basic_consume(callback,queue=queue_name,no_ack=True)
channel.start_consuming()
```

---

If I gets the message within the timeout period specified client is supposed to print the message and should stop consuming further .

Can anyone help me how to set the timeout in the client ?

Answer (score 0):

This problem in deadline. Then deadline moment happen function callback called without any args. So you can change your code

```
def callback(ch=None, method=None, properties=None, body=None):
    if ch is None or method is None or properties is None or body is None:
         print "Deadline"
    else:
         print " [x] %r:%r" % (method.routing_key, body,)
```